# Heroku Django app returning error heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: django, macos, postgresql, heroku

My error in log, working on localhost deploys ok then i get unstuck!

Feb 19 16:32:44 mysite heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysite.herokuapp.com request_id=0bf47868-4a4f-41c3-ba3e-9035d543e35 fwd="121.211.230.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Checked all the previos post but nothing is working.

**Procfile;**

```
web: gunicorn nmn.wsgi --log-file -
```

**wgsi.py:**

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Please can someone help? anyone?

```
Feb 19 18:28:37 newmusicninja heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `gunicorn nmn.wsgi --log-file -` 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  [2015-02-20 02:28:39 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14199 (3) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  [2015-02-20 02:28:39 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  [2015-02-20 02:28:39 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  [2015-02-20 02:28:39 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.1.1 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  [2015-02-20 02:28:39 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process: 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  Traceback (most recent call last): 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      worker.init_process() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.callable = self.load() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      return self.load_wsgiapp() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      __import__(module) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  ImportError: No module named nmn.wsgi 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  Traceback (most recent call last): 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      worker.init_process() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.callable = self.load() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      return self.load_wsgiapp() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      __import__(module) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  ImportError: No module named nmn.wsgi 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  [2015-02-20 02:28:39 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  Traceback (most recent call last): 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module> 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      sys.exit(run()) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      super(Application, self).run() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      Arbiter(self).run() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.manage_workers() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.spawn_workers() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      time.sleep(0.1 * random.random()) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      self.reap_workers() 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:      raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR) 
Feb 19 18:28:39 newmusicninja app/web.1:  gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3> 
Feb 19 18:28:40 newmusicninja heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 1 
Feb 19 18:28:40 newmusicninja heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: What you are showing is not the full traceback. Can you share the full traceback ??

Answer (score 2):

Why you are refer gunicorn to nmn ( Is that actual project ).

> gunicorn just needs to be called with the location of a module containing a WSGI application object named application

(i,e)

```
mysite
    -- mysite
           -- settings.py
           -- wsgi.py
           -- urls.py
    -- yourapp
           -- models.py
           -- admin.py
           -- views.py
```

So in your Procfile include this will work `web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -`

Comment: I have also (ProcFile)configured then why happening?

Comment: Can you tell me the error ? And what you put in procfile

Comment: web: gunicorn BacKEnd.wsgi --log-file -
here BackEnd is the project name

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BacKEnd'
on heroku

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution I don't know how it works but its actually effective.
Just install pipenv by typing the following in cmd `pip install pipenv`.
After this try to push again and it will not crash.I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
pip install django-heroku
```

in cmd prompt,

......................................................

then modified

```
django-heroku==0.3.1
```

in requirements.txt

......................................................

and the last, add

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

in very bottom in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error because of an error in wsgi.py module in this line.
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')`

Answer (score 0):

this is where you error is

```
ImportError: No module named nmn.wsgi
```

you might be using an outdated package, try updating the package that is using nmn.wsgi

Answer (score 0):

check Procfile if it contains your project name! if not, edit-

web: gunicorn your_project.wsgi --log-file

else;

pip install pipenv

Answer (score 0):

A simple `pip install gunicorn` resolved my issue.

I realised I deployed to Heroku and forgot to install gunicorn.

**Dont forget to updated the `requirements.txt` file too**